# Main page blank space?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image: Main page error]
This isn't present on other SEs I've visited, so the new header alone isn't the cause..? Though they may have already fixed it on the sites I checked. In case it matters, this view is from Firefox and persists on questions, profiles and the main feed (above).

Comment: What version, and OS of firefox? I see the same box in latest stable chrome (31), Windows 8.1.

Comment: Chrome 32.0.1700.19 beta on Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Chrome 31.0.1650.63, Firefox 25.0.1, Safari 5.1.10, and Opera 11.60 on OS X 10.6.8 have it too.

Comment: Chrome 31.0.1650.57, Firefox 7.0.1, Firefox 12, and Firefox 25.0.1 on Win 7 have it too.

Comment: This will be site-specific because we have a custom site design. Curiously, it *doesn't* show here on Meta, though I see it too on main. (FF 25.0.1; Win 7 Pro)

Comment: Chrome 31.0.1650.57 m (which it’s telling me to update), Windows XP Pro SP 3.

Comment: Chrome 31.0.1650.63 m (post update) has the same issue as well.

Comment: I'm on Firefox Aurora 27.0a2 and I see the same on main but not meta, like @SevenSidedDie found.

Comment: Firefox 25 on Windows 7 has it.

Comment: Seeing it on super-old Safari as well (version 5.0.6 on OS X 10.5.8). On main site but not meta. I think it's safe to say it's a quirk of the new layout rather than a browser-specific issue.

Answer (score 8):

I pushed a fix for this. It will go live after our next production build.

Comment: Thank you verymuch Jin!

Comment: Pixel perfect. 